# custom settings to set event reminder

Tags: datetime, customsetting, before-trigger

I'm trying to put (-60) value in the reminder time. it works but it is hard coded.
I want it from custom settings so admins could edit the numbers from the GUI.

```
trigger setReminderEvent on Event (before insert){
    If(trigger.new[0].StartDateTime != null){
        trigger.new[0].IsReminderSet = TRUE;
        trigger.new[0].ReminderDateTime = trigger.new[0].StartDateTime.addMinutes(-60); 
        //CUSTOM SETTINGS INSTEAD-converted to datetime 
    }
}
```

someone please show me the right way for this.
I can't use Integer or String for the .addMinutes(), only DateTime,
How do i covert a text/numbers field from custom settings into DateTime in the trigger?
I cant make the custom settings field DateTime because I could not tell it to be 'minus 60 minutes'.

better way or approach ?

Answer (score 3):

Implement a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` and use an `Number` field. Example code might look like:

```
Integer offset = MyHierarchSetting__c.getOrgDefaults().Event_Reminder_Offset__c;
record.ReminderDateTime = record.StartDateTime.addMinutes(offset);
```

Please note you should get your trigger logic into a separate `Apex Class`, and act on all records, not just the first.

Comment: this does not work because .addMinute() is looking for datetime type, and was getting Integer type.